# Android Slide a view down when another view's visibility is changed from gone to visible

Tags: android, view, visibility

I have a view that has the visibility set to gone most of the time(View A) and another view below it that's always visible(View b), there are occasions when View A view is set to visible from some condition, when this happens, View B will not be visible (mostly because View A blocked it when it appears). I'm wondering if there is a way for the system to re-position view B to below view A when it appears.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/require_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/payment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/quantity_label"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/payment"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contact Information"
            android:textColor="#90CAF9"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `View A` above the `View B` in the `LinearLayout`, when you set both A and B to visible, the layout with redraw and you'll see `View A` above `View B`.  Make sure your `LinearLayout` has an `orientation` of `vertical`.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to change the height of your first LinearLayout to "wrap_content" it's at present set to "match_parent". So in case in you make your View A visible it acquires the whole available space on screen and your View B never appears.

Answer (score 0):

Linear layout is suitable for your design. Following sample shows how can you do same.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button1"
            android:id="@+id/button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button2"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In above , when you try to make visible first linear layout and hide second linear layout the layout which is visible will take full screen and vice versa. If you set both layouts to visible the layouts are properly visible (First Layout and below of it second layout).